# some question about the nodes and topics in ros_industrial_client package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I read the industrial_robot_clientgeneric_implementation(http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_robot_client/generic_implementation)and have some confusion about the nodes and topics mentioned in this page.

1.In this page, there three nodes,robot_state,motion_**interface and joint_trajectory_action. The robot_state just publishes three topics without subscribing anyone topics while motoin***interface is completely opposite. Does the robot_state node decode the message received from robot controller using simple message? And the motion**_interface subscribes the message form topics and encode them using simple message then send to robot controller? Can I understand the process of these two nodes like this?

2. Does joint_trajectory_action node act as an action server?I noted that this node subscribed topics like goal, cancel and states and publishes topics like feedback, status etc.where is the action client?
   3.I'm a beginner so I still don't know how to understand the whole process of the implecatioin process and of industrial_client and simple_message,so I hope someone can give me some suggestions.
   Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268851/some-question-about-the-nodes-and-topics-in-ros_industrial_client-package/) by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> In this page, there three nodes, `robot_state`, `motion_interface` and `joint_trajectory_action`. The `robot_state` just publishes three topics without subscribing anyone topics while `motoin_interface` is completely opposite. Does the `robot_state` node decode the message received from robot controller using simple message? And the `motion_*_interface` subscribes the message form topics and encode them using simple message then send to robot controller? Can I understand the process of these two nodes like this?

yes, that is correct.

> Does `joint_trajectory_action` node act as an action server? I noted that this node subscribed topics like `goal`, `cancel` and states and publishes topics like `feedback`, `status` etc.

Yes.

> where is the action client?

That could be any compatible client. One example could be MoveIt, or a custom node that you write yourself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0